# Using a4j and JavaScript to modify managed bean value from server

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

Hello I was wondering if there was a way to pass a managed bean value (string) from server to the JavaScript to trim few words on the string.

Below is a sample code I am working with, but am unsure how to get it working.

```
<rich:column styleclass="#{table.displayClass}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value ="vocabulary"/>
    </f:facet>

    <a4j:support event="onchange"
                 reRender="vocab_value"
                 oncomplete="get_vocab('#{table.currentstring}')"/>
<h:outputText id="vocab_value" value="#{table.currentstring}" styleClass="#{row.displayClass}" />
</rich:column>
```

The JavaScript `get_vocab()` works perfectly (uses indexof and substring to retrieve the vocab word) but I can't not seem to get the above code working in order to display the value that is trimmed. The page itself is refreshed every minute.

Comment: The data attribute is exactly what you need, what isn't working?

Comment: I am trying to modify the display value of '#{table.currentstring}' before full load of the html page. Please note I am not trying to change the value itself but just change the display of it on screen by going through the get_vocab javascript. I am not even sure if a4j is required to do what I am trying to do here and I am open to ideas. Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: You didn't answer my question; the code you edited is ok so what does not work?

Comment: Thank you very much for paying attention to this question and sorry for the late reply :). I've been tinkering with the code and trying to edit the code on the question to provide update. I haven't tried the code above yet but just wanted some expert opinion on whether this will work. From your last comment, will this code work?

Comment: Seems like the code above did not work because my program can not use a4j:support. Is it possible to achieve what I mentioned without using a4j:support?

Comment: If you run into an error then please update the question. Why would your app not be able to use `a4j:support`? What version of RichFaces are you using?